# How to find the boot option to select OS?

Tags: installation, boot

I am facing some problems after installing Ubuntu.

My computer wants to reboot after installing Ubuntu, but after I restart it, Windows 8 boots automatically. I cannot find any boot option to select operating system, it just boots my Windows 8. I cannot see the drive where I have installed Ubuntu.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu, and what version? Was it by disc, or Wubi.exe?

Comment: Also mention if you are trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop which came pre-installed with Windows 8. If so, look at the following question, follow the answers given there and if you still face issues then edit your question with details: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed in using wubi, you should get a menu (f8 if it dosen't pop up), if you did a dual boot install, hold she shift key right after turning it on.